# How do I create a pivot table for many excel sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a pivot table for each excel sheet in VBA but am getting the error "Method or data member not found" meaning I probably have something named wrong but can't figure it out. This is what I have tried. It is part of a larger sheet

```
Dim WSheet As Worksheet

For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Dim rngDestPvt As Range
Set rngDestPvt = WSheet.Range("H3")
   
Dim rngSrcData As Range
Set rngSrcData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion  'source

    WSheet.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngSrcData, _
                Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngDestPvt, _
                TableName:="LATE", DefaultVersion:=8

    With WSheet.PivotTables("LATE").PivotFields("PAY CODE")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    
    With WSheet.PivotTables("LATE").PivotFields("NAME")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    
    WSheet.PivotTables("LATE").AddDataField WSheet.PivotTables( _
        "LATE").PivotFields("PAY CODE"), "Count of PAY CODE", xlCount
    
    
     With WSheet.PivotTables("LATE").PivotFields("PAY CODE")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    
    WSheet.PivotTables("LATE").PivotFields("PAY CODE").ClearAllFilters
    WSheet.PivotTables("LATE").PivotFields("PAY CODE").CurrentPage = _
        "Late Clock In"
        

Next WSheet
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Only workbook has pivotcaches.

Comment: `Set rngSrcData = WSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through (F8) would pinpoint the problem.

It could be due to redundant table names, try:

```
TableName:="LATE_" & WSheet.Name,
```

instead of:

```
TableName:="LATE",
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried that and it works but creates the same table on each sheet. I wish to create a new table for each sheet. Each table will have the same fields etc since each sheet will have the same headings but the information and values will be different.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you note is because a `Worksheet` object doesn't have a `PivotCaches` member but a `Workbook` does - see [Workbook.PivotCaches method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.pivotcaches). As the `Workbook` is the parent of the `Worksheet` then you can add `.Parent` to the line that references `PivotCaches` ie

```
WSheet.Parent.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngSrcData, _
            Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngDestPvt, _
            TableName:="LATE", DefaultVersion:=8
```